Azure Revoke Sessions at Microsoft Entra ID using Azure Cloud CLI
Is it a method of revoking sessions for a user in Microsoft Entra ID using the Cloud CLI?
I am looking at the documentation for AZ AD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest and I cannot find it there. But maby it is called Microsoft Entra ID and not AD?
